# Display cookies in request headers in Safari 7

Tags: cookies, safari, safari-web-inspector

When examining request headers in Chrome or Opera using their default console, I can see in the request headers what cookies have been sent to the server and if server is trying to set a cookie, I can also see Set-Cookie header.

However, in Safari 7.1.2 I don't see these information, but I see other information such as Accept,, User-Agent, Referer etc.

Do I need to enable something to see the cookies in the Safari's console? How can I view cookies that are being sent together with the request?

Thanks

P.S. I know that I can see cookies in the resources, but I need to know specifically in which requests the cookies are present.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I somehow found out that Safari rewrote my headers (so instead of all capital letters, it only left the first letter capital and this broke my code).

Comment: @leopik. Headers should be treated case insensitively. There are tons of things out there, such as proxies and CDNs, and as you discovered browsers, that can manipulate the case in the headers. Cookie keys, however, are CASE SENSITIVE, even though some frameworks (in browser and in server) that treat them as if they were insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, modern versions of Safari will omit the "Set-Cookie" and "Cookie" headers in the responses, and requests, respectively. I guess the reason is "oh, you can see what cookies are set in the "Resources / Cookies" tab. However, that's of poor consolation when you're trying to determine if any Cookie headers are being sent, which is my situation.