# SameSite properties not there when inspecting cookies on Safari Web Inspector

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, safari-web-inspector, js-cookie

I'm testing out using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library to set samesite cookies and I'm trying to see if I was able to set `sameSite="Strict"` and `sameSite="Lax"` cookies or first-party cookies on Chrome, Firefox and Safari but all I see is a line through the SameSite column when inspecting the cookies in Safari console.

Is this meant to happen?

I know its working on Chrome and Firefox as tested and inspected cookies on both before.

**Screenshots of inspecting cookies on Chrome 81 on MacOS:**
[image]

**On Firefox 76 on MacOS:**

[image]

**But on Safari v13.1 on MacOS:**

[image]

Does that mean that sameSite was not set for these cookies? Or that I just can not see them?

Trying to find a way to validate that I did the right thing in setting sameSite cookies on Safari, note that I used the same methods using js-cookie for Chrome, Firefox and Safari:

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
Cookies.set("strict", "llok", { sameSite: "strict" });
Cookies.set("lax", "llok", { sameSite: "lax" });
```

**EDIT:**
Tried checking document.cookie in console and doesn't print the right info, looks like this in Safari console:

```
"lax=llok; strict=llok; test=nice; CookieConsent=true"
```

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837597/display-cookies-in-request-headers-in-safari-7?rq=1

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026956/on-safari-cookies-are-not-saved-when-sent-with-redirect?rq=1

Comment: trying this right now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250921/how-to-view-cookies-in-safari-10